# How are primitives types objects in Scala?

Tags: scala

How are primitive types in Scala objects if we do not use the word "new" to instantiate the instances of those primitives? Programming in Scala by Martin Odersky described the reasoning as some enforcing by a "trick" that makes these value classes to be defined abstract and final, which did not quite make sense to me because how are we able to make an instance of these classes if its abstract? If that same primitive literal is to be stored somewhere let's say into a variable will that make the variable an object?

Comment: You are mixing implementation and runtime with language definition. At language level all values are objects, so all values have methods, all values can be passed around, functions are also values, etc. How primitives are handled is work of the implementation, the language simply specifies that the only way to instantiate those are using literals.

Comment: "how are we able to make an instance of these classes if its abstract?" Well, that's the trick. The Scala compiler pretends that primitives are proper objects that are instances of `Int`, `Long`, etc. even though they're really not in the JVM

Comment: @user could you expand on how these primitives are not truly Objects but the compiler pretends that they are?

Comment: When you use an Int in generics, for example, the compiler used a boxed Integer. However, most of the time, it tries to use primitive ints instead

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use scala 2.13 with implementation of [literal types](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5310). For this explanation you can think of `type` and `class` as synonyms, but in reality they are different concepts.

To put it all together it worth to treat each primitive type as a set of subtypes each of which representing type of one single literal value.

So literal `1` is a value and type at the same time (instance `1` of type `1`), and it is subtype of value class `Int`.

Let's prove that `1` is subtype of Int by using 'implicitly':

```
implicitly[1 <:< Int] // compiles
```

The same but using `val`:

```
val one:1 = 1
implicitly[one.type <:< Int] // compiles
```

So `one` is **kind of** an instance (object) of type `1` (and instance of type `Int` at the same time because because `Int` is supertype of `1`).  You can use this value the same way as any other objects (pass it to function or assign to other `vals` etc).

```
val one:1 = 1
val oneMore: 1 = one
val oneMoreGeneric: Int = one
val oneNew:1 = 1
```

We can assume that all these `vals` contain the same instance of one single object because from practical perspective it doesn't actually matter if this is the same object or not.

Technically it's not an object at all, because primitives came form java (JVM) world where primitives are not objects. They are different kind of entities.

Scala language is trying to unify these two concepts into one (everything is classes), so developers don't have to think too much about differences.

But here are still some differences in a backstage. Each value class is a subtype of `AnyVal`, but the rest of the classes are subtype of `AnyRef` (regular class).

```
implicitly[1 <:< AnyVal] //compiles 
implicitly[Int <:< AnyVal] // compiles

trait AnyTraint
implicitly[AnyTraint <:< AnyVal] // fails to compail
implicitly[AnyTraint <:< AnyRef] // compiles
```

And in addition, because of its non-class nature in the JVM, you can't extend `value classes` as regular class or use `new` to create an instance (because scala compiler emulates `new` by itself). That's why from **perspective of extending value classes** you should think about them as **final** and **from perspective of creating instances manually** you should think of them as **abstract**. But form most of the other perspectives it's like any other regular class.

So scala compiler can **kind of** extend `Int` by `1,2,3 ..` types and create instances of them for `vals`, but developers can't do it manually.

Comment: I'd rather assume that they mean `scala> new Int(5) // error: class Int is abstract; cannot be instantiated`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin hard to say. Anyway, the global picture may inspire for further exploration.